# Wie sagt man in Deutsch "axioms of class existence"?

Tags: translation

Ich brauche eine Hilfe, ich möchte wissen, wie man auf Deutsch "*axioms of class existence*" sagt. Der Kontext ist [das](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Mendelson.27s_variant)

Comment: Was sagt denn eine kl. Wörterbuchrecherche nach den Wörtern? Der deutsche Wikipediaartikel befasst sich nicht mit dem Aspekt?

Comment: Im WP-Artikel [Klassenlogik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klassenlogik) ist von _Existenzaxiomen für Klassen_ die Rede.

Comment: Die direkteste Übersetzung ins Deutsche wäre wohl „Klassenexistenzaxiome“.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Buch *Logische Grundlagen der Mathematik* (Seite 99) schreibt

> Klassenexistenzaxiome